# Book series with weird family, witch mom

Tags: story-identification

I read these books when I was a kid about a brother and sister and their weird family. Basically the mom was a witch of some kind, and had a cool book that the kids got in to. They lived in a huge castle thing with their parents and grandma.

It was a lot like the Addams Family, but it was a series of books! I can’t even really remember what happened in them, but I think that in one, the dad goes missing for a while. Also, it might have been set in Italy because I remember the men calling each other “Monsignor” ?

The books were pretty short, never more than 200 pages long that I can remember.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_Dead_series

Comment: I read this when I was younger, and found it *very* enjoyable.

Comment: If this answers your question, feel free to accept it by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/182579/what-childrens-fantasy-series-has-furry-hardback-covers-and-stone-skimming-drag

Answer (score 5):

### *Pure Dead* series

This sounds a lot like the *Pure Dead* series (*Pure Dead Magic*, *Pure Dead Frozen*, and so forth). To quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_Dead_series):

> The chronicles follow the Strega Borgias, a quirky, bizarre, **Italian
>   family**: Signor and Signora Strega-Borgia (Luciano and Baci) and their
>   four children, Titus, Pandora, Damp and Nieve, who live with their
>   mythical companions in their **fictitious home StregaSchloss**, in Argyll.
>   It consists of two trilogies: Pure Dead and Deep. The Strega-Borgias
>   share similarities to **The Addams Family**.

Further, the mother is a witch, as you say:

> Signora Baci Strega-Borgia - Luciano’s wife, mother to Titus, Pandora,
>   Damp and Nieve. She dislikes being pregnant. **Baci attends a witch
>   academy**, although she is absolutely appalling at magic.