# What children's fantasy series has furry hardback covers and stone-skimming dragons?

Tags: story-identification, books

I was recalling a fantasy series I read when I was younger not too long ago. Woe is me, my younger cousin was in the room, and now he wants me to find out what the series was so he can read it too.

I'm looking for a fantasy series, probably aimed at 8-12ish year olds. I read it in the mid-2000s, so it's not too ancient. I distinctly remember some of these books having hardback furry covers - sort of like velvet, but longer fibres.

I also remember:

- The series involved a family living in a dilapidated and falling-apart mansion (possibly in Scotland, and I *think* it was called StregaSchloss... or something on those lines).
- I think the children's names were Titus and Pandora.
- There was a group of some sort of fantasy animals, possibly dragons, who I believe were family pets. One of the books involved one of these creatures skimming stones on a lake.

and... not much more. I'm hoping the names are enough to be able to pick the right series out, possibly with some help from a furry cover or two.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## This is almost certainly the [Pure Dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_Dead_series) series.

Also known as the Strega Borgia chronicles, the books were published in two trilogies, Pure Dead and Deep. Written by Scottish author and illustrator Debi Gliori for older children, the series is described as being a "black comedy" series.

---

## Details remembered

**The series involved a family living in a dilapidated and falling-apart mansion (possibly in Scotland, and I think it was called StregaSchloss... or something on those lines).**

The books are also known as the Strega Borgia Chronicles about the Strega Borgia family living in StregaSchloss in Argyle.

**I think the children's names were Titus and Pandora.**

- Signor Luciano Strega-Borgia - Father.
- Signora Baci Strega-Borgia - Mother.
- **Titus, son of the above.**
- **Pandora - Titus's younger sister, ten or eleven during the series.**
- Damp - The youngest Strega-Borgia up till the final book.

  > - Nieve (a.k.a. "little no name" or "somebody else entirely") - The new baby and younger son of the Borgias'.
- Strega-Nonna (Amelia) - Cryogenically preserved six-times-great grandmother of Titus, Pandora, Damp and Nieve.
- Don Lucifer di S'Embowelli Borgia - Luciano's evil half-brother.
- Don Chimera - father of Luciano Strega-Borgia.

**There was a group of some sort of fantasy animals, possibly dragons, who I believe were family pets. One of the books involved one of these creatures skimming stones on a lake.**

- Ffup - Dragon
- Sab - Gryphon
- Tock - Crocodile
- Knot - Yeti
- Nestor - Half-dragon
- Multitudina the Illiterat - Illiiterate rat
- Terminus - Highly intelligent rat
- Tarantella - Pet spider
- The Sleeper - Loch Ness Monster
- Orynx - Salamander

---

## The Books

### Pure Dead Trilogy

- [Pure Dead Magic (2001)](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/444357.Pure_Dead_Magic)
- [Pure Dead Wicked (2002)](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/727334.Pure_Dead_Wicked)
- [Pure Dead Brilliant (2003)](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/727329.Pure_Dead_Brilliant)
- [Deep Trouble (2004)](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2554177.Deep_Trouble) (a.k.a: [Pure Dead Trouble](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/565442.Pure_Dead_Trouble))
- [Deep Water (2005)](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/727336.Deep_Water) (a.k.a: [Pure Dead Batty](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/565437.Pure_Dead_Batty))
- [Deep Fear (2006)](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/565439.Deep_Fear) (a.k.a: [Pure Dead Frozen](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/565438.Pure_Dead_Frozen))

Comment: Hahah I've never seen someone comment *that* before :)

Comment: I comment that I'll add more details when I'm back from [*\*insert task here**] all the time. The real question is if I ever _do_ come back!

Comment: It just seems so... chill. Like, I read that comment and then I say to myself, *You know what, I'm gonna eat something*.

Comment: @user477343 Welcome to the life of Edlothiad (⌐■_■)

Comment: :: *rap music plays in the background* ::

Comment: ^_^ From a practical standpoint, too, if you spend a bunch of time giving more than just the plain answer and a short description why, someone else will snipe you. Fastest gun and all that.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I'd given reasonable confirmation in the first couple of minutes. I try not to post stubs.

Comment: @Edlothiad: I was not implying elsewise, just stating that it's a common reason for the "here's the answer, will provide more details later". As the old saying goes, "Perfection is the enemy of good enough."

Comment: That's the one :)